# Can I get discord server name without id or convert it from id to name - discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Is there way to get Discord server name without id or convert it from id to name.
This Code get server id.

```
let server = msg.guild.id; 
    msg.channel.send(server);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `msg.guild.name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `msg.guild.name` to access the name of the guild.

If you only have the ID of a guild, you can use:

```js
let guild = bot.guilds.cache.get(id).name;
```